# monodevelop 3 - support for "Attach to process"

Tags: monodevelop

does MonoDevelop 3 support attach to process? If so can someone point out where it is or any possible workaround.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is: No, not as far as i know.

However if you are looking to do debugging without launching the project from MonoDevelop there is an option of using the  [Soft debugger described here](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime:Documentation:SoftDebugger). The workflow for doing that is:

1. Enable Custom commands to the softdebugger in monodevelop by setting environment variable MONODEVELOP_SDB_TEST to some value
2. Start monodevelop
3. Go to the Run -> Run With -> Custom Command Mono Soft Debugger
4. Enter a port number and an IP address of your machine where the debugee can reach MonoDevelop. Leave the other fields empty.
5. Press `Listen`.
6. Start the application with parameters --debug and --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=[IP specified in monodevelop]:[Port specified in monodevelop]

And then you can inspect what is going on like normally using breakpoints stop exection, inspect variables and so forth. Notice that this enables you to deploy across machines as long as they can be reached over the network.

[image]

I know this is not "Attach to process" but as you are very limited in the description of your intent, this might be of value to you.

Answer (score 0):

At first , I  also can not find "attach to process "in my Monodevelop (2.8.6.3) IDE,

but when I installed "GUN debugger plugin for monodevelop"  ,I can find "attach to process " in "RUN" memu.
   So ,You should install the GNU debugger plugin for monodevelop for "attach to process"

ps:my monodevelop is in Ubuntu 12.04; "GUN debugger plugin for monodevelop" can be find in “ monodevelop in Software Centre ”.