# What is expected in the "Output" field of Monodevelop's Custom Command Mono Soft Debugger dialog?

Tags: debugging, mono, monodevelop, remote-debugging

I [can't use normal debugging in Monodevelop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963904/monodevelop-waiting-for-debugger), so I am trying to [debug remotely as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12395786/226958).
Here is the whole procedure:

---

In a terminal, type:

```
export MONODEVELOP_SDB_TEST="YES"
monodevelop &
```

Monodevelop starts.

1. Open your solution
2. `Run -> Run With -> Custom Command Mono Soft Debugger`
3. Fill the fields:

   1. Command: `/home/nico/src/CmisSync/bin/SparkleShare.exe`
   2. Arguments: `-debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:10000` (not sure if needed)
   3. IP: `127.0.0.1`
   4. Port: `10000`
   5. Output: `1`
4. Press `Listen`
5. Back to the terminal, press:

`mono --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:10000 ./bin/SparkleShare.exe`

---

**PROBLEM:** Monodevelop crashes at step 4, as soon as I have pressed `Listen`:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Standard output has not been redirected
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardOutput () [0x00043] in /build/buildd/mono-2.10.8.1/mcs/class/System/System.Diagnostics/Process.cs:663 
  at MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.ProcessWrapper.CaptureOutput () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00016] in /build/buildd/mono-2.10.8.1/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Thread.cs:703
```

Same error when I press `Connect` instead of `Listen`.

Maybe I entered the wrong value for `Output`? [The source code shows that an integer value is expected](http://searchco.de/codesearch/view/20107542#296).

This part of Monodevelop is very experimental (they are not planning to implement exception handling), so sending them a bug report would not be productive in this case... I am pretty sure I just misunudertood something.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the correct procedure:

In a terminal, type:

```
export MONODEVELOP_SDB_TEST="YES"
monodevelop &
```

Monodevelop starts.

1. Open your solution
2. `Run -> Run With -> Custom Command Mono Soft Debugger`
3. Fill the fields:

   1. Command: Empty
   2. Arguments: Empty
   3. IP: `127.0.0.1`
   4. Port: `10000`
   5. Output: Empty
4. Press `Listen`
5. Back to the terminal, press:

`mono --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:10000 ./bin/SparkleShare.exe`

Now application can be debugged in Monodevelop!