# SIGABRT error on Monodevelop's custom command mono soft debugger on remote device

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I run Ubuntu on my host PC and remote ARM device. 
I'm trying to use Monodevelop on host PC to remotely debug c# code running on ARM board.
I follow [What is expected in the "Output" field of Monodevelop's Custom Command Mono Soft Debugger dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739952/what-is-expected-in-the-output-field-of-monodevelops-custom-command-mono-soft)
Everything works fine if I don't set break point. However, everything I try to step over a break point, I got error message like below:

```
Assertion at debugger-agent.c:4349, condition `tls->frame_count' not met
```

Stacktrace:

```
Native stacktrace:


Debug info from gdb:


Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.


Aborted
```

It doesn't matter where and what code I set break point. 
Anyone has some ideas?

Comment: I've seen similar errors about TLS.  Does your unmanaged code use pthreads?